# Trying to move cell data from one column to another

Tags: jquery

I am beginner in JavaScript, I spent 5 hours trying to make arrows to move text from column to another like this [image]

sadly I failed to do that by myself ! my try is [here (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/wasim/4be1jcxe/) 
 this is the JS code:

```
$(function () {
    $(".table tr > td.right > span").each(function() {
        $(this).append("<span class='left_arrow'></span>")
    });

    $(".table tr > td.left > span").each(function () {
        $(this).append("<span class='right_arrow'></span>")
    });
});

$(".table tr > td > span >span").on('click', 'span', function () {
    var selected = $(this).parent().text();
    selected.remove().appendTo(selected.parent().siblings("right"));
});
```

can anyone help me in this problem?

Comment: Your objective is not clear, Please elaborate it a bit

Comment: @Saksham I need to move text from second column to the next and vise verse using arrows images

Comment: Is this static? how do you differentiate between right/left arrows?

Comment: @TJ I use its position to decide what's the appropriate style for it... if it's in second column I use left arrow, if it's in third column I use right arrow

Comment: That is why i asked whether this is static or not. there can be a fourth column as well. So this is static?

Comment: @TJ yes, it's static

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can swap the content according to your current markup as follows:

```
$(".table tr > td > img").on('click', function () {
  var $siblings = $(this).parent().siblings();
  var contents = $siblings.map(function(){
    return $(this).html();
  });
  $siblings.each(function(i){
    $(this).html((i==0) ? contents[1] : contents[0])
  })
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/4be1jcxe/5/)

Comment: I wish if I can select your answer as correct answer too, thanks

Comment: well the other answer is obviously not *the answer for the question* since it'll only work with a single row, which is why i bothered posting :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not quiet sure whether I got your question right, but you could try it like this:

HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td><input id="cellLeft" type="text" value="This is the content."></td>
    <td><img id="changeContent" src="http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/50849.png"></td>
    <td><input id="cellRight" type="text" value=""></td>        
</tr>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// When the arrow is clicked, trigger the function
$('#changeContent').click(function () {
    // Save the content of both fields in variables
    var contentLeft = $('#cellLeft').val();
    var contentRight = $('#cellRight').val();
    // Write the contents back into the fields but sides changed
    $('#cellLeft').val(contentRight);
    $('#cellRight').val(contentLeft);
});
```

});

Working Fiddle: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4be1jcxe/3/)